# Book App Tutorial iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am totally beginner in programming.
I played a bit with xcode.

But my question is:
How to make an application like a book with pictures, texts and sounds, and that when children change their page, image, text and sound are in the context?
I need to find a tutorial for it or if someone wants to teach us.
We really want to teach us to do, we walk with our own legs after.

Thank you for your attention and help.

Answer (score 3):

There is no tutorial that covers EVERYTHING

But there are tons of documentation provided by apple

- [Introduction to The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163)
- [Getting Started with iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneGeneral/index.html)
- [Your First iOS Application](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html)
- [iTunes U: Stanford — Developing Apps for iOS by Paul Hegarty](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=395605774)
- [iTunes U: Stanford — iPhone Application Development by Alan Cannistraro and Josh Shaffer](http://ax.itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/iphone-application-development/id384233225)
- and the search box on stackoverflow.com (upper right)