# UIAlert for deleting a row in tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uialertview

I have this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

[array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if(buttonIndex == 0)//OK button pressed
{

}
else if(buttonIndex == 1)//Annul button pressed.
{

}
}
```

I want to show alert view before I cancel a row of `tableView`, then put instruction of `commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle` in first `if` of `UIAlert` method delegate...
is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you just try it? My guess: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: but if I write instruction inside first "if" (OK) there is an error because it don't know  "(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)" or " tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];"

Comment: So you have to have a ivar, where u save this information to, and use it in the method called my the alertbox.

Comment: how can I do this? I don't know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save the cell's indexPath to an ivar and use that information within the method called by the alert view.

```
@interface MyClass : … {
    NSIndexPath *deleteIndexPath;
}
@end
```

In your implementation:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        deleteIndexPath = indexPath;
        //code for UIAlrtView
        // …
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex == 0)//OK button pressed
    {
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:deleteIndexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:deleteIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Comment: in first "if" it don't like indexPath.row and tableView

Comment: if you are inside of a UITableViewController, try self.tableView

Comment: did u change `indexPath.row` to `deletedIndexPath.row`?

Comment: ok deleteIndexPath is ok, but I have ever the error in tableView and don't work with self.tableView

Comment: Does your class inherit from UITableViewController?

Comment: yes I have: @interface List : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate>
Do I write this? IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;? myTableView?

Comment: no, it is not inheriting. it is just implementing the protocols. it most likely be `@interface List : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate>`

Comment: ok...but if I write UITableViewController in .h when I launch my app it crash because I have a UIViewController

Comment: Probably now things are wired up falsely. You will have to fix at least your nib files. By seeing in your profile, that you have post 5 questions just today regarding cocoa-touch developing, I think, you have a lack of understanding of many fundamentals concepts. you should make sure you understand *object-orientated programming in objective-c *Model-View-Controller pattern *delegation *… [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190910/book-app-tutorial-iphone/4191037#4191037) you'll find a small collection of good resources for the beginning.

Comment: I solved!!!! for tableView I used UITableView *table; then I write table = tableView; and after [table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:deleteIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; It work fine+

Comment: yeah, in this case that should work. But keep in mind, that a tableView should have a UITableViewController.

Comment: yes I know, but if you start with a UIViewController and after you need  tableview you must add UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource...no?