# Adding a new cell to a Table View from a different view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I was wondering if there is a way i could have a table view displayed on one view then when you hit the "add" button it would flip you to a second view where you would type in the name that you want the new cell's text label to say. Then you would hit a "done" button and it would flip you back to the first view where it would have the newest item. And you would be able to add however many cells you want.

Comment: Xcode is no relevant for this question. That is just an IDE. The language is called Objective-C and the framework Cocoa-Touch.

Comment: sorry. Will work on that

Comment: I'd like to advise you to work yourself through some tutorials — ASAP. Here a small collection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190910/book-app-tutorial-iphone/4191037#4191037

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa and Cocoa touch are based on an MVC pattern.  What that means is there's separate layers each with responsibilities - the model, the view and the controller.

The model is the data and the operations on that data, the view is what you see and the controllers mediate between them.

So, in your example, you wouldn't add a cell from a different view.  That violates the fundamental pattern.  Instead, what would happen is the view where your adding the data would call to the model to add the item and the view would go away.  Then, when it returns to the view that lists the items, it would query the model (which contains the new object) and the list would contain the object.

The two views are decoupled and they share the same model.  It allows you to change interfaces and storage without breaking most of your app because they're decoupled.

For example, you could have a table view controller that gets it's list from querying your model class.  Your model class could be a singleton ( [MyModel sharedInstance] ) that offers a method like:

```
NSArray* items = [model getItems];
```

That method could be backed by Sqlite (search for fmdb), CoreData storage, a simple file, or even in memory data like an NSMutableArray. Your UITableViewController implements the callback methods by calling into your model.

Then, you offer an Add button which calls this to modally show your AddItemController.

```
[self presentModalViewController:addItemController];
```

After the user supplies the data on the form and clicks the Done/Save button, you call your model to save the item which is a class with the data:

```
[[MyModel sharedInstance] saveItem:item];
```

That writes to your storage.

Then, upon return to your UITableViewController, in viewWillAppear, you re query the data and call for the table view to reloadData;

```
_items = [[MyModel sharedInstance] getItems];
[[self tableView] reloadData];
```

Now the table shows the data you just added.

There's other variations but that's a basic one with MVC separation.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. What do u think is the best way to save data? As in uses not much memory (since you might be adding multiple rows) that doesn't take much time to put together? I was thinking about using a .plist, but then I thought "would i have to use a new .plist for every row i want to add"? That was my first method to save but If you can give me a better method or help on how to use a .plist better that would be great! Thanks

Comment: a plist is fine for stroring a list of items.  a key question there is what are the querying patterns.  If just give me the list of items and other basic filters then plist is fine.  If you get into more complicated access patterns, queries and searches, then you want the power of something like a sql engine behind you.  Start simple though ...

Comment: If you do someday look at needing more powerful data capabilities, Core Data and Sqlite are the obvious choices on iOS.

Comment: how would i save multiple data entries to one .plist? Also how would i have the table view only add the newest data "string"? AND how would i have it so you can have an unlimited amount of rows?

Comment: Use NSArray's [array writeToFile:location atomically:YES]; to save an array of items to a plist

Comment: "unlimited number of rows" - be aware that to add one item to the list, you have to write the*whole* list again to a file.  You wouldn't add the latest - you write the whole list.  If you have a large number of items, you should use sqlite or coredata.

Comment: Is there a way I can add multiple section headers? and then place certain objects under them???

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add, putting this in plain words...
Whatever source that you use for your table to load cells from (an array, dictionary, class, you name it...) then you create the "add" button, make it push the new view controller, then when you press the "done" button on your navigation bar, add the object's property (the name text field info, or whatever you need) to the source you load your table view data from.