# How to Call a Controller Class (delegate) method from View Class Event in Objective C/Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

lets say I have an NSWindow Class, that has several events for mouse and trackpad movements
for example this code

IMHO, I think this should be good programming, it is similar to pointing an action of a button to its method in controller. 
in MyWindow.m Class I have (which in IB I have set the window class to it)

---

```
@implementation MyWindow
- (void)swipeWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
NSLog(@"Track Pad Swipe Triggered");
/* I want to add something like this
   Note that, Appdelegate should be existing delegate, 
not a new instance, since I have variables that should be preserved*/
[AppDelegate setLabel];
}   
@end
```

and in My AppDelegate.h I have

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
IBOutlet NSTextField *label;
}
-(void)setLabel;
@end
```

and in my AppDelegate.m I have

```
-(void)setLabel
{
[label setStringValue:@"swipe is triggered"];
}
```

I have tried #import @class, [[... alloc] init], delegate referencing in IB (I made an object class of MyWindow - thanks to the answer of my previous question )
that latter seems the closest one, it works if both of the classes are delegates, so I could successfully call the "setLabel" action from a button in a second controller (delegate class)'s IBAction method, 
but this View Events seem not communicating with the delegate's action although their code is executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a message to the AppDelegate class, not the instance of your AppDelegate class which is accessible from the NSApplication singleton ([NSApplication sharedApplication])

```
[AppDelegate setLabel];
```

This is wrong, to get the delegate do this:

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

then send the message to that instance:

```
[appDelegate setLabel];
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. Where do you guys learn this! I stumbled through many books/websites/apple documentation without any success but just this one line of code did everything for me.

Comment: Objective-C/Cocoa development has great documentation. not only provided by apple. here is a collection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190910/book-app-tutorial-iphone/4191037#4191037

Comment: In Cocoa, you access the application object via the global variable `NSApp`, and therefore the line to get the delegate can be `[NSApp delegate]`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell nice, didn't know about the short cut.

Comment: It is nice. Drives me crazy that they didn't include that in iOS.