# Implementing toggle feature in a UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uibutton

I want to know how to add the toggling feature to a `UIButton`, something like the user taps a unselected button the button becomes selected and stays selected till the user taps it again there by making unselected like it was before.

I was thinking of making an `IBAction` which changes it from unselected to selected, how can I do that?

Heres what I tried:

```
-(IBAction)toggle {

    //Toggle on implementation.

        button.selected = YES;
        button.highlighted = NO;
        button.enabled = YES;

    //Toggle off implementation.

    if (button.highlighted == YES) {

        button.selected = NO;
        button.highlighted = YES;
        button.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Problem...

```
-(IBAction)toggleFav {

    if (favButton == nil) {

        UIImage *unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favUntapped.png"];
        UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favTapped.png"];
        [favButton setImage:unselectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [favButton setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [favButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    }       

    if([favButton isSelected]){

        //Add to menu.
        [favButton setSelected:NO];
    } else {

        //Remove from menu.

        [favButton setSelected:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UIImage *unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"];
        UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"];
        UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [b setBackgroundImage:unselectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [b setBackgroundImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [b addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [b setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:b];
    }       
    return cell;
}

-(void) buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if([sender isSelected]){
        //...
        [sender setSelected:NO];
    } else {
        //...    
        [sender setSelected:YES];
    }

}
```

Your `toggleFav` code doesn't make much sense.
`if (favButton == nil) {` checks, if `favButton` is present. But if you are wiring it up with IB, it should always been there at that point. And if it wasn't how could the button call this method? So do it like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    //....
    UIImage *unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favUntapped.png"];
    UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favTapped.png"];
    [favButton setImage:unselectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [favButton setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [favButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    //....
}


-(IBAction)toggleFav:(UIButton *)sender {
    if([sender isSelected]){
        //...
        [sender setSelected:NO];
    } else {
        //...    
        [sender setSelected:YES];
    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/tree/master/Favorite) you'll find an example project, with a DetaiView, that holds a Button with the 2 states.
**Note:** I am saving the information of what button was selected in the NSUserDefaults. You should not do that. Instead you'll want to save it in the model. But as I dont have informations on your model, I am just using NSUserDefaults.

Comment: as i wrote in ur [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081154/adding-favorites-feature-to-iphone-app-iphone-sdk/4081265#4081265): the stars are not related to the tableview. they are part of a button. u can add a button to any view, that is (deriving from) a UIView. If u don't know this, u REALLY should read some [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190910/book-app-tutorial-iphone/4191037#4191037)

Comment: man, i have to say: ur attitude is really not helpful ("I don't want", "I don't have any code", "still waiting", "still waiting (again)"). There are a lot people around here, willingly to help u. But u should convince them, that u tried ur best to manage it on ur own. meaning: referring to docs, showing code, explaining exactly where u got stuck.

Comment: I tried the code but when I go out of the view where I implemented it. It doesn't remember the state. Also I implemented your code under a IBAction.

Comment: There was a small error: I was painting a new button at top of the old every time the cell was reloaded. see my fixed coded.

Comment: I only copied the -(void)buttonpressed. I did all of the rest in Interface Builder.

Comment: in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` i put the button generation into the `if (cell == nil)` block

Comment: I tried this out with a button. But it doesn´t save the state.

Comment: It should. You must do something wrong — probably something like I did. But without seeing ur code, i cannot even give a good guess.

Comment: I will add it to my question.

Comment: I will have a look on it tomorrow, as i need to go now.

Comment: I doesn´t work, but I should tell you that this view is a detailView. Which when a user taps a tableView cell is goes to this.

Comment: So when exactly does the button looses it state?

Comment: I don´t know exactly when it lost its state, but I copied the code and builded it and the button didn´t show up.

Comment: U should never just copy code, but understand it. in my `-viewDidLoad` i didnt add the button to the view. `[self.view addSubview:favButton]`

Comment: thanks for your instructions, but then does [self.view addSubview:favButton] add favButton to my view or does it create a new reference to my favButton?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html%23jumpTo_51 Seriously: Did you consider walking through some basic docs? this is simple but important stuff. here i posted some useful links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190910/book-app-tutorial-iphone/4191037#4191037

Comment: This is what I did. In IB I changed my buttons default and selected state to my unselected image and selected image. Then I implemented your code without the code under viewDidLoad.

Comment: Amd did u wire the button up?

Comment: yep, I wired my button to my favButton outlet.

Comment: how does ur property for favButton look like?

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)hitButton:(UIButton*)button
{
    buttonOnFlag = !buttonOnFlag;
    if( buttonFlag )
        [self performSelector:@selector(setHighlight:) withObject:button afterDelay:0];
}

- (void)setHighlight:(UIButton*)button 
{
    button.highlighted = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use button.highlighted property

Comment: the button just goes on and off straight away?

Comment: or else use some flag value and set two diff button images accordingly

Comment: If u are using one button means go for two diff images,one for highlighted state and another for disabled state

Comment: Actually I have just made an IBAction with this in it: button.selected = YES; and button.highlighted = NO; and when I tap the button now it stays highlighted like I wanted but when I tap on it again it doesn´t go off. It just flickers.

Comment: use if condition in IBAction if(button.highlighted==NO) set as YES and vice versa

Comment: I tried this: if (favButton.highlighted == YES) {
  
  favButton.selected = NO;
  favButton.highlighted = YES;
 }

Comment: well I created an IBOutlet for favButton and an IBAction for toggle and all of them are connected.

Answer (score 0):

You should code like this:

```
-(IBAction)toggle:(id)sender {

    //Toggle on implementation.
   if (sender.highlighted == NO)
     {
        sender.selected = YES;
        sender.highlighted = NO;
        sender.enabled = YES;
     }

    //Toggle off implementation.

   else{

        sender.selected = NO;
        sender.highlighted = YES;
        sender.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it should be sender?

Comment: ok, but when I run it, It gets errors like highlighted is not a structure or union.

Comment: to be more exact I get stuff like this: Request for member "highlighted" in something not a structure or union.

Comment: UIButton *resultButton = (UIButton *)sender;
resultButton.highlighted=YES;